# Movie identification: YA 80's movie about a legion of robots overrunning a planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, young-adult

I have very tenuous memories of this movie, watched on VHS in the mid-eighties.  The hero, a young man, had to rescue a young woman (princess?) from a massive number of obsidian, or at least shiny black, robots or golems or something.  Something significant about their hearts, maybe hearts were transplanted from living creatures into the robots?  The cover depicted a bunch of the robots in a wedge advancing across a featureless plain, the lead robot holding the woman in its arms.  The hero and his friends (mutants/aliens/monsters?) are standing on a cliff ledge overlooking the robots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[Gandahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film))" (AKA "Light Years") from 1988.

You didn't say if it was animated or not, but here is the picture you described, maybe?

[image]

The full movie is on YouTube. Here it is.

Comment: My word. This looks almost as good as Krull.

Comment: @Valorum. HaHa! Yeah, they're both great '80s flicks.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the hit film [Krull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(film)) (1983)?

The core of the movie is our hero trying to rescue his wife-to-be (a princess, no less) from the clutches of an evil alien robotic army.

[image]

The VHS back cover depicts some of the robot/warriors

[image]

Comment: See if you can find the Joe Bob Briggs review for Krull, it is scream aloud funny.

Comment: Oh, look - he's got a fidget spinner!